# Copy list with random pointer error?

Tags: java, linked-list, deep-copy

Surfing on leetcode i wanted to try this question: A linked list is given such that each node contains an additional random pointer which could point to any node in the list or null.
Return a deep copy of the list. However, there seems to be an error with my code since it is not passing the grader and its not telling me why.

There are 3 phases of my code.

1. I insert new node between 1st and 2nd node, so..on.
2. I copy the random pointer of original to the copy node's random pointer.
3. I separate the two lists.

Can you please help? Thank you.

---

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list with a random pointer.
 * class RandomListNode {
 *     int label;
 *     RandomListNode next, random;
 *     RandomListNode(int x) { this.label = x; }
 * };
 */
public class Solution {
    public RandomListNode copyRandomList(RandomListNode head) {
        // Note: The Solution object is instantiated only once and is reused by each test case.

        if(head == null) return head;

        RandomListNode current = head;
        RandomListNode temp = null;
        RandomListNode solution = null;
        //insertion
        while(current != null){
            RandomListNode clone = new RandomListNode(current.label);
            temp = current.next;
            current.next = clone;
            clone.next = temp;
            current = current.next.next;
        }

        //copy random
        current = head;
        while(current != null){
            if(current.random!=null){
            current.next.random = current.random.next;
            }
            current = current.next.next;
        }

        //separation
        current = head;
        solution  = current.next;
        while(current != null){
            temp = current.next;
            current.next = current.next.next;
            temp.next = temp.next.next;
            current = current.next.next;
        }

        return solution;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you jump one too far in `current = current.next.next` at the very end -- you already have assigned `current.next` to `current.next.next` (which is the next original node), so I think the last line in the last loop should just be `current = current.next`?

Comment: your right. also i wasnt advancing temp pointer either. i found the solution. thanks